# after expanding the row in kendo treelist, how to hide the element of the parent row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a kendotreelist with three columns and expandable rows. If i expand the row then second column element of the parent row should hide. How to implement it in jquery???

Comment: $(element).closest(row).find(whatToHide).hide() . This helps you ?

Comment: No, it will hide element in all row. But i want to hide only parent row element

Comment: Actually i am not getting how to implement as while expanding the kendo treelist row it should hide the element.